# PHP Curl, where can I find a list of integer equivelants of constants

Tags: php, curl, integer, constants

I'm using the Codeigniter Curl library, and the author uses the integer equivalents of the curl options. The php manual says this for [curl_setopt_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php):

> The keys should be valid curl_setopt()
> constants or their integer
> equivalents.

How do I figure out what the integer equivalents are for a constant? I've googled it but haven't found anything.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$arr = get_defined_constants(true);
var_dump($arr['curl']);
```

Comment: Useful, totally forgot about `get_defined_constants()`.

Comment: Actually this helped me see all the constants and I could then easily search for the integer.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on **ajreal**'s answer

```
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$curlOptLookup = preg_grep('/^CURLOPT_/', array_flip($constants['curl']));

var_dump($curlOptLookup);
```

The above gives an integer lookup, so the following would work:

```
echo $curlOptLookup[119]; // outputs "CURLOPT_FTP_SSL"
```

If you want the options, the correct way round it needs to be flipped again:

```
$curlOpts = array_flip($curlOptLookup);

echo $curlOpts['CURLOPT_FTP_SSL']; // outputs 119
```

Comment: @FMC: Good point, adapted to do the `array_flip()` on the way in to the `preg_grep()` call, which obviously needs reversing afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

@Orbling 's technique for getting an array indexed by the curlopt values is *mostly* correct, except you should filter out the `CURLOPT_*` elements *before* flipping the array, since there are collisions in values between the various `CURLOPT_*`, `CURLE_*`, `CURLSSH_*` (etc.) options that are *not* simply aliases for each other.

For example, `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLE_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` both have the value 47. When you call `array_flip($constants['curl'])`, the latter entry overwrites the former, and you lose `CURLOPT_POST`.

So maybe do this instead:

```
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$curlOptKeys = preg_grep('/^CURLOPT_/', array_keys($constants['curl']));
$curlOpts = array_intersect_key($constants['curl'], array_flip($curlOptKeys));
$curlOptLookup = array_flip($curlOpts);

echo $curlOpts['CURLOPT_POST']; // 47
echo $curlOptLookup[47]; // 'CURLOPT_POST'
```

Answer (score 1):

Echo/print them...

Example:

```
<?php
echo(CURLOPT_URL);
```

Comment: @Mark I've added a reverse lookup to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just beware that some constants have the same value associated with them, in the answers above these will get overwritten. To get a full list you can not populate an array.

```
$arr = get_defined_constants(true);
foreach ($arr['curl'] as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('/CURLOPT/',$k)) {
            print $v." => '$k',\n";
    }
}
```

For example Output For 10026:-

```
10026 => 'CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD'
10026 => 'CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD'
10026 => 'CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD'
```

Comment: The constants with the same integer value are the same thing, they just have different names.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589658/1094092