# What are duplicate Curl Options and why do their constant names differ?

Tags: php, curl

In the PHP curl library options for a request can be set using the [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) function, for example

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

allows curl to follow redirect responses to the given "`Location: ...`" headers. The constant `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` represents an integer denoting the option in the curl library, here the example integer value is `int(52)` for `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

When obtaining the constant name by the option integer value it is not possible to exactly find out which option constant was used because some constants have the same value (for example shown in [Get a constant name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15970749/367456)).

This leads to the question: Why are there duplicate constant names for the same options and what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The different named option constants are representing the same settings or options. This is due to changes in the underlying curl library over time. You can not only interchangeably use them in PHP but also in the curl library because PHP imports those constants from the libcurl c library.

This is also what I could imagine in the beginning that some of those options are just an alias. Take for example the curl option `int(10009)`, it has two different named constants assigned:

1. **`CURLOPT_READDATA`:** undocumented constant
2. **`CURLOPT_INFILE`:**  Stream resource of the file that the transfer should be read from when uploading.

The first one is undocumented in the PHP manual. The curl library has it documented here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html - It effectively has the same meaning as *`CURLOPT_INFILE`* in PHP. This can be easily tracked in the [curl list of options and when introduced](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/aa5808b504fa7d3093c480b4c4c8d82d32921709/docs/libcurl/symbols-in-versions) as part of their source:

```
 Name                           Introduced  Deprecated  Removed

CURLOPT_READDATA                7.9.7
CURLOPT_INFILE                  7.1           7.9.7
```

Also the status of an alias can be checked as well in the sources ([ref](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/5d2327929932bb18b0c683583f398855f0a31fed/include/curl/curl.h#L592)):

```
#define CURLOPT_INFILE CURLOPT_READDATA /* name changed in 7.9.7 */
```

`CURLOPT_INFILE` is clearly an alias of `CURLOPT_READDATA` because it has been deprecated. The PHP manual does not yet reflect this.

There is another group of different named option constants which are standing for the same option:

1. **`CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`:** String of the password required to use the `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` or `CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE` private key. Added in cURL 7.16.1.
2. **`CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`:** String of the password required to use the `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` certificate.
3. **`CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`:** String of the secret password needed to use the private SSL key specified in `CURLOPT_SSLKEY`.

First again the version check:

```
 Name                           Introduced  Deprecated  Removed

CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD               7.17.0
CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD           7.1.1         7.17.0
CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD            7.9.3         7.17.0
```

This shows already that the later two are deprecated. Let's see the constant definitions ([ref](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/5d2327929932bb18b0c683583f398855f0a31fed/include/curl/curl.h#L1650) & [ref](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/5d2327929932bb18b0c683583f398855f0a31fed/include/curl/curl.h#L1657)):

```
...
/* These are scheduled to disappear by 2009 */

/* The following were added in 7.17.0 */
#define CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD
...
#define CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD
...
```

So it can be clearly said that both `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD` and `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD` are an alias of `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`.

As this reviews all the collisions in the constant names I'm aware of for the PHP curl extension and [the PHP extension imports the constants from the libcurl C library](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/curl/interface.c#REGISTER_CURL_CONSTANT), you can be assured that those are aliases.

It's perhaps most safe to use the non-deprecated constants in your code for future compatibility:

- **`CURLOPT_READDATA`** (since 7.9.7)
- **`CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`** (since 7.17.0)

This would be in opposite to:

- **`CURLOPT_INFILE`** (since 7.1, now deprecated since 7.9.7)
- **`CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`** (since 7.1.1, now deprecated since 7.17.0)